# Displaying item with a specific parameter in the index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website for poetries.
There are two different type of poetries: `famous` or amateur.

I built the CRUD functions to display all the poetries (famous and amateur, without distinction) and this is working as intended (see the `PoetrisController` code below).

Now, I want to give the possibility to the user to choose if he wants to see only the amateur poetries or famous ones.
Basically the user clicks the link "Amateur" or "Famous" in the navbar and he is redirected to a new page listing only amateur or famous poetries.

My question is: should I create another Controller (for example `PoetriesFamousController`) and creating a index function inside it to display only the famous poetries or there is a way to use the already existing `PoetriesController` to show only the "famous poetries" if the user clicks the link in the navbar?

**PoetriesController:**

```
 class PoetriesController < ApplicationController
 skip_after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:home, :about, :newsletter, :disclaimer, :new, :create]
    
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:home, :about, :newsletter, :disclaimer, :new, :create]

  before_action :set_poetry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :amateur_poetries]

  def index
    if params[:search]
      @poetries = policy_scope(Poetry).search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").limit(30)
    else
      @poetries = policy_scope(Poetry).order("RANDOM()").limit(30)
    end
  end


  def show
    authorize @poetry
  end

  def new
    @poetry = Poetry.new
  end

  def create
    Poetry.create(poetry_params)
    redirect_to poetries_path
  end

  def edit
    authorize @poetry
  end

  def update
    @poetry.save
    redirect_to poetry_path(@poetry)
  end

  def destroy
    @poetry.destroy
    redirect_to poetries_path
  end



  private

  def poetry_params
    params.require(:poetry).permit(:title, :author, :body, :poster, :country)
  end

  def set_poetry
    @poetry = Poetry.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**Poetries.rb**

```
class Poetry < ApplicationRecord
  def self.search(search)
    where("lower(title) LIKE ? OR lower(author) LIKE ? OR lower(country) LIKE ? OR lower(born) LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  get 'poetries', to: 'poetries#index', as: :poetries
  get "poetries/new", to: "poetries#new"
  post   "poetries", to: "poetries#create"
  get "poetries/:id/edit", to: "poetries#edit"
  patch "poetries/:id", to: "poetries#update"
  get 'poetries/:id', to: 'poetries#show', as: :poetry
  delete "poetries/:id", to: "poetries#destroy"
```

Comment: Does your Poetry model have a property that distinguishes the type (famous, amateur, etc..)? Or is that determined by some other means?

Comment: It is determined by another mean. The famous poetries are seeded using db:seed from an excel file. In this excel file all the poetries belongs to an entity called Admin. Therefore, all the famous poetries have "Admin" for the attribute "poster" in the database. So I know that if poetry.poster == "Admin", it means that the poetry is "famous".

Comment: if it's not upload by "Admin", what is the content of poetry.poster?, can the content has more than one item for example "Guest","Member" etc? ?

Comment: If it is not uploaded by "Admin" it means a user is logged into the website and he writes a poetry and submit it via a form. Such form has a hidden value equal to: poetry.poster == current_user.
So if it a poetry does not have poetry.poster == "Admin", it must have poetry.poster == current_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some idea for your problem

In your view (sample idea)

```
poetries type: 
<%= select_tag :poetries_type, options_for_select(["Famous","Amateur"]), include_blank: true, :class => 'form-control'  %>
```

in your controller:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    if params[:poetries_type] == "Famous"
      @poetries = Poetry.famous.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").limit(30)
    elsif params[:poetries_type] == "Amateur"
      @poetries = Poetry.amateur.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").limit(30)
    else
      @poetries = Poetry.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").limit(30)
    end
  else
    @poetries = policy_scope(Poetry).order("RANDOM()").limit(30)
  end
end
```

Poetries.rb, add two scope for famous an amateur

```
def self.amateur
  where("poster != ?","Admin")
end 

def self.famous
  where("poster = ?","Admin")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I am not sure where I should add the first part of your answer (f.label...). Should I add it in index.html.erb? In this case what does the "f" of "f.label" refers to?

Comment: f.label is just to create label, I corrected my answer without f.label to make it more simple, meanwhile if you do not using bootstrap you can change :class => 'form-control'  to other class that you have or just remove it

Comment: Thanks! One question more, don't I need a submit button so that the "search" is actually inited? Now, if the user selects "Famous", nothing happens because there is not submit to the code I added in my view.

Comment: I saw you using [:search] in your params, you can put select_tag inside form_tag that has already has with search text_box , so the idea user can search based on title but also can filter based on famous or amateur (two functions inside one search submit)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to add two more actions to your controller.

```
def famous
  @poetries = #get the famous ones
  render :index
end
def amateur
  @poetries = #get the amateur ones
  render :index
 end
```

Then update your routes

```
 get 'poetries', to: 'poetries#index', as: :poetries
 get 'poetries/famous', to: 'poetries#famous'
 get 'poetries/amateur', to: 'poetries#amateur
 # rest of the routes
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this create a problem with the show action once i click on a poetry in the index to display it? I guess it will tell "id: 'famous' not existing".

Comment: I don't think it will as long as you define those two routes before the show, that's why I put them directly under the index. I threw together a repl to test it out. 
https://repl.it/@rnice4christ/KnownEvilArea